# Where abouts in the Persian Empire did the Jews live?

Tags: history, geography, babylonian-exile, persia

The original deportations of Jews occurred in Nebuchadnezzar's era and so they would have settled in Babylon regions, but whereabouts in the **Persian Empire** did the Jews live? Were they dispersed much further? Of course, we know that Esther resided in Susa, (ex. Elam) but she was the king's wife. My question relates to the general center of population of dispersed Jews between 500 to 300 BCE.

Comment: Maybe try Professor Simkovich, seems like something she'd know...